# Why this 10 threads always output the same thread name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I ran this code

```
NUM = 0
def count():
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(t.getName()+":"+"NUM is "+str(NUM))

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=count)
    t.start()
```

The output is

```
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
```

I know why the NUM is always 10, but why is the thread name always the same? Every thread runs `print(t.getName()+":"+"NUM is "+str(NUM))`; the `t` should not be the thread that gets the cpu time's one?  I think the name should not be the same.

When I changed to this

```
NUM = 0
def count():
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    name = t.getName()
    time.sleep(1)
    print(name+":"+"NUM is "+str(NUM))

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=count)
    t.start()
```

It works as I expect:

```
Thread-1:NUM is 10
Thread-3:NUM is 10
Thread-2:NUM is 10
Thread-4:NUM is 10
Thread-5:NUM is 10
Thread-7:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
Thread-9:NUM is 10
Thread-6:NUM is 10
Thread-8:NUM is 10
```

Comment: Where is `t` set?

Comment: `t` is an *outer* variable. It is repeatedly set until it reaches 10 for instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're referencing the *global* name `t`.  By the time the sleeps end, the loop is over, and `t` remains bound to the last thread (the 10th thread) the loop created.

In your alternative, the results aren't actually defined.  There you reference the global `t` *while* the loop is still running, so it's likely to be bound to the most recent thread created - but doesn't *have* to be.

Note:  if you don't have convenient access to the thread object currently running, you can use

```
threading.currentThread()
```

to get it.  Then

```
threading.currentThread().getName()
```

will return the name of the thread running it.

Comment: I tried you code,it actually works.But why when using `threading.currentThread()` works, the document said > Return the current Thread object, corresponding to the caller’s thread of control. The ` t ` has been set to the 10th thread in the for loop, the `currentThread()` should not be the same 10th thread? @Tim Peters

Comment: "The caller" is the thread that calls `currentThread()`, so is _always_ the thread you intended it to be ;-)  This has nothing to do with how the threads were created (and so, in particular, has nothing to do with whatever the global `t` happens to be bound to at the time).

Comment: @lxacoder Think of it this way: you are assuming that each call to `count` runs at least as far as the reference to `t` *before* the main thread can change its value. But why should it? The only thing that is guaranteed is that each thread is *created* in order; you can't make any assumptions about how much time each thread gets to execute before being suspended again.

Answer (score 4):

Your function queries for a `t`, but **no `t` is defined in the function**:

```
def count():
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    name = t.getName() # use outer t
    time.sleep(1)
    print(name+":"+"NUM is "+str(NUM))
```

The fallback mechanism of Python thus will look for a `t` in the direct outer scope. And indeed, you assign to a `t` in the outer scope, so it will take that value.

Now since you write **`t = ...` in a `for` loop**, that `t` changes rapidly. It is very likely that the `for` loop has already reached the last value - especially because of the threading mechanism of Python - before the first thread actually fetches that `t`. As a result, all the threads fetch the `t` referring to the *last* constructed thread.

If we however **rewrite the function to**:

```
NUM = 0
def count():
    name = t.getName() # t fetched immediately
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(name+":"+"NUM is "+str(NUM))
```

I get:

```
Thread-11:NUM is 10
Thread-12:NUM is 10
Thread-13:NUM is 10
Thread-14:NUM is 10
Thread-15:NUM is 10
Thread-17:NUM is 10
Thread-16:NUM is 10
Thread-19:NUM is 10
Thread-18:NUM is 10
Thread-10:NUM is 10
```

on my machine. Of course this does *not* guarantee that every thread will grab the *correct* thread, since it is possible that only later in the process, the thread will start working and fetches the `t` variable.

Comment: I  think I have know it's why after your help. thanks.

Comment: This certainly reduces the odds of the current thread losing the race to access `t` before the main thread changes it, but it doesn't eliminate it.

Comment: @chepner: yeah I know, I only wanted to demonstrate that here we grab different `t` values. But I added a note at the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have the same problem for both the thread name and the count `NUM`: by the time you get to the first `print` statement, all 10 threads have been started.  You have only *one* global variable `t` for the thread, and *one* global `NUM` for the count.  Thus, all you see is the last value, that for the 10th thread.  If you want separate values printed, you need to supply your code with a mechanism to report them as they're launched, or keep a list through which you can iterate.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to try this:

```
NUM = 0
def count():
    global NUM
    NUM += 1
    num = NUM
    name = t.getName()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("t.getName: " + t.getName() + ", name: " + name + ":" + ", NUM: " + str(NUM) + ", num: " + str(num))

for i in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=count)
    t.start()
```

Result:

```
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-10:, NUM: 10, num: 10
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-6:, NUM: 10, num: 6
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-3:, NUM: 10, num: 3
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-5:, NUM: 10, num: 5
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-4:, NUM: 10, num: 4
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-9:, NUM: 10, num: 9
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-7:, NUM: 10, num: 7
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-2:, NUM: 10, num: 2
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-1:, NUM: 10, num: 1
t.getName: Thread-10, name: Thread-8:, NUM: 10, num: 8
```

t.getName() is a function call, which is a reference. By the time the print functions reached the console, `t` references to the latest thread.

Comment: Like any global variable, `t` is subject to a race condition and you can't be sure which thread `t` references when any particular thread's function actually runs.